# How to add phone number in Twitter when it's already in use for another account?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to add my number to my Twitter account but I can't because it says it's used in another account but actually I bought this number recently and I didn't add it to any account, so maybe the old owner added it to an account.

So, how can I delete my number from unknown account?

I tried this steps but it doesn't work because they actually close this page:

> Navigate to twitter.com on a computer. This link only works if you're logged out of Twitter.
> Click on the Activate your account link located on the home page as shown below.
> Enter your phone number when directed, along with the country code.
> If your phone number is linked to a Twitter account, we'll send your phone a text message containing a verification code. Use this code to confirm that the mobile number belongs to you.
> On the following page, Twitter will ask you to complete your Twitter profile. Your username will already be filled in. That username belongs to the same account your phone is tied to.

Also I sent 'stop' to 40404 but it doesn't work.